# Keep taking a list of files until exited

Tags: java, list

The program takes in one file at a time from the command line and executes it.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    fileName = scan.nextLine();
    File xmlFile = new File(fileName);
    // Do SOMETHING with xmlFile
}
```

Basically I want to take a list of files from the commandlines unless the user does `CTRL+D`.
How do i change it?

Comment: use a keylistener and then you could use a second while loop where you give a boolean as parameter e.g. : while(!ctrlDpushed){...} or you have an if statement in the the current while loop with if(ctrlDpushed) and make a break if thit statement is true

Comment: although IMO easier to test if `line` equals `-1` or `q` or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using a Scanner would be to use a stream:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
Stream lines = br.lines();
Consumer processFile = new Consumer() {
    public void accept(Object o) {
        File xmlFile = new File(o.toString());
        // Do SOMETHING with xmlFile
    }
};
lines.forEach(processFile);
```

Ctrl+D is end-of-stream so it'll just take you out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{

    line = scan.nextLine();
    if(line.equals("-1"){
     break;
    } 
    fileList.add(line);

}

for(String file: fileList){
File xmlFile = new File(file);
//process
}
```

Else keep doing as per your original code and use CTRL+C to exit the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Pass files as argument like below :

```
java XYZClass file1.csv file2.csv
```

and access that in your code like below ;

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(args[0]);
File myFile = new File(url.getPath());
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

Comment: I have done this. Actually I need 2 ways to input files.
1. As arguments (as u did)
2. Without arguments (as I want)

Comment: @VeilEclipse - Can you put all the files in one folder ?

Comment: No!
`java XYZClass
file1
file2
file3
Keep reading until CTRL+D`